# WCF (413) Request Entity Too Large - also after changing configuration

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration-files

I have a problem connected with error 413 Request Entity Too Large when I try to send bigger data through WCF service. I changed configuration adding maxReceivedMessageSize and some others but it didn't help.
Below I paste my config:
Config on server side:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="BasicBehavior" name="xxx">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="EndpointBehavior" bindingConfiguration="BasicBinding"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" name="GenerateDocuments" contract="xxx" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicBinding" sendTimeout="00:05:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
       <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="BasicBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndpointBehavior">
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And here is my binding config on client side (on client config is created programmatically):

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Name = "BasicBinding";
binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
binding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2000000;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;
```

And finally client calls service:

```
GenerateDocumentsClient service = new GenerateDocumentsClient(ConnectionManager.GetBinding(), ConnectionManager.GetEndpoint(MainFields.DatabaseRegister))
```

I also changed attribute uploadReadAheadSize but it also didn't help.
I have no idea what can I do to make it right. I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

try this in the Service web.config(befor system.serviceModel):

```
  <system.web>
       <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>
     <system.webServer>
     <security>
         <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647"></requestLimits>
          </requestFiltering>
      </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: It also didn't help. I configured it earlier in IIS :(

Answer (score -1):

OK, this topic can be closed. I found really stupid reason why I couldn't do that so the problem is solved.

Comment: If the question is no longer relevant, you can delete it, since you asked it.

Comment: May I ask how did you solve the problem? We are also in the same situation. Thanks.